# Access to key/values pairs of HashMaps within an Object[]

Tags: java

I have an Object[] which entails lots of Objects of the type HashMap. The HashMap looks like this:

```
Object[]
{id=15, name=Hello}
{id=27, name=Hello}
{id=15, name=Hello}
```

I have tried to cast it to HashMap[], however no luck.

I would like to iterate and retrieve a list of names. Hope you can help me.

Comment: can you post the construction process of that object ?

Comment: This is hopelessly confused. Show use the actual code you're having problems with, not some out-of-context "example" that does not even remotely compile.

Comment: How is it confusing? ;-) i am accessing an xml-rpc interface which gives me back a HashMap if I give it an Argument of a singel id to process. Now if I give it an Object[] of ids it will return me an object [] with HashMaps. I don't know the backend of the software and it is written in Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't  cast a array holding T1 to a array holding T2. An array in a actual object with a type of itself. This is the cause of your failure to cast.

However i doubt that you really have a HashMap array in there. The dump you are providing doesn't look like a hashmap dump.

However to answer your original question you should do something like this:

```
    // assuming hashes is your array
    Object []hashes;

    for (Object object : hashes) {
        HashMap hash = (HashMap)object;

        for (Object o : hash.values()) {
            System.out.println(o);
        }
    }
```

this will print all the values on all the hashes from your array.

Comment: Hey I do have a java.util.HashMap in there, I printed out the getClass().getName() of the objects in the array.

Answer (score 3):

Even if an array of Objects only contains HashMap instances, it's still an array of Objects, and can't be cast to an array of HashMaps.

You may, however, iterate over the array, and cast each element to a HashMap (or Map). If you're not sure every object in the array is a Map instance, then use the instanceof operator:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>(objects.size());
for (Object o : objects) {
    if (o instanceof Map) {
        Map map = (Map) o;
        String name = map.get("name");
        if (name != null) {
            names.add(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your question because it's syntactically wrong. But,

You may use `ArrayUtils.toMap()`:

```
  Map map = ArrayUtils.toMap(  new String[][]{
     {"@GRP@", artifactInfo.getGroup() },
     {"@ART@", artifactInfo.getName() },
     {"@VER@", artifactInfo.getVersion() },
     {"@PACK@", artifactInfo.getPackaging() },
     {"@NAME@", artifactInfo.getFileName() },
     {"@DESC@", req.getQueryString() },
  } );
```